# Where can I get Rating Page of Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I would like to use same design in my app as has default rating/review page in Windows Phone 8 - (Page which appears when user wants to review an app). Where can I get the screen shot of this page? Or is there aviable original template for this page?

Comment: Are you trying to mimic the page for something else (i.e. let users rate movies), or just have the user rate YOUR APP?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly for movies. I want to have similar design.

Comment: It's very easy. Do you have any problems with xaml?

Comment: You can use the rating control from windows phone toolkit.. http://phone.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can take the screenshot on your phone and copy it to your computer. There is no template for that page that is publicly available, why would you need it?

If you want to enable rating your app from the phone itself, use [MarketplaceReviewTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.marketplacereviewtask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).
If you want to reuse the star rating control, you can get it from the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/): see RatingControl.

Comment: The problem is that I don't own WP8 phone. I have already tried to find this screenshot on the internet, but not successfully.

Comment: I will be glad if you make it for me.